# Parsing jsoup list

Tags: android, android-listview, html-parsing, jsoup

I created a list in which i parse a webpage. I can display the titles and the first image of the first article but what i want is display the image for each article. This is the code:

EDITED CODE

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    public static final String TAG_TITOLI = "titoli";
    private static final String TAG_IMMAGINE = "immagine";
    ListView lista;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    public ImageView immagine;
    public ImageView logoimg;

    static final String BLOG_URL = "http://www.multiplayer.it";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lista = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.main_lista);//recupero lista da id



        //View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.riga_listview, null);
        //immaginebtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.immaginebtn);
        //creo ed eseguo l'asynctask
        ParsingPaginaWeb parsing = new ParsingPaginaWeb();
        parsing.execute("");

        // Immagine btn
        /*immaginebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Execute Logo AsyncTask
                new Logo().execute();
            }
        });*/
        //new Logo().execute();

         // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
            lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String titoli = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.riga_listview_titolo)).getText().toString();
                    immagine = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1));

                    // Starting new intent
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_TITOLI, titoli);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_IMMAGINE, bitmap);
                    //in.putExtra(TAG_CONTENT, cont);
                    startActivity(in);

                }
            });

    }

    private class ParsingPaginaWeb extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

        ArrayList<String> titoli; //lista dei titoli
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(); 
        //ArrayList<String> content; //lista delle descrizioni

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {   
            //prima di eseguire il parsing inizializzo gli arraylist
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Multiplayer.it");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Caricamento articoli...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();

            titoli = new ArrayList<String>();
            bitmap = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(); 
            //content = new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
                Elements nodeBlogStats = doc.select("div.news-col-0 h3"); //per multiplayer.it Elements nodeBlogStats = doc.select("div.news-col-0 h3"); per ftv #comunePartINI > option
                for(Element sezione : nodeBlogStats)
                {
                    titoli.add(sezione.text());

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // In caso di errore
                Log.e("ESEMPIO", "ERRORE NEL PARSING");
            }
            return null;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            // dopo che ho eseguito il parsing mostro i dati nella listview
            // usando il custom array adpater ParsingArrayAdapter
            ParsingArrayAdapter adapter = new ParsingArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, titoli, bitmap);
            lista.setAdapter(adapter);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            new Logo().execute();
        }


    }

    // Classe per caricamento immagini..

    // Logo AsyncTask

    private class Logo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Immagini");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading images...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
                // Using Elements to get the class data 
                //Elements img = document.select("div.news-col-0 img[src]");
                // Locate the src attribute
                for(Element img : document.select("div.news-col-0 img[src]")) {
                    String ImgSrc = img.attr("src");
                // Download image from URL
                InputStream input = new java.net.URL(ImgSrc).openStream();
                // Decode Bitmap
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Set downloaded image into ImageView
            logoimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            logoimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

           // ParsingArrayAdapter adapter = new ParsingArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, titoli);
           // lista.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

}
```

How can i solve?

EDIT:
Adapter class:

```
public class ParsingArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    //ID and resources references
    private final static int LAYOUT = R.layout.riga_listview;
    private final static int TITOLO = R.id.riga_listview_titolo;
    private final static int IMMAGINE = R.id.imageView1;

    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap ; 

    ArrayList<String> titoli; //lista dei titoli

    Context c; //context
    LayoutInflater inflater; //layout inflater

    public ParsingArrayAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> titoli, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap)
    {
        super(context,TITOLO);
        this.c = context;
        this.titoli = titoli;
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return titoli.size(); //List lenght 
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos,View view,ViewGroup parent)
    {
        CacheRiga cache; //cache
        if(view==null)
        {

            view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, parent,false); 
            cache = new CacheRiga(); //inizializzo la cache
            cache.titolo = (TextView) view.findViewById(TITOLO); //title

            cache.immagini = (ImageView) view.findViewById(IMMAGINE);//collego descrizione


            view.setTag(cache);
        }
        else
        {
            cache = (CacheRiga) view.getTag(); 
        }

        cache.titolo.setText(titoli.get(pos)); //I set up the title

        //cache.immagini.setImageBitmap(bitmap.get(pos));



        return view;
    }

    private class CacheRiga { // Cache class
        public TextView titolo; // Title cache
        public ImageView immagini; // Image cache
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you might consider only using English when you write a program. This especially includes naming comments and variables, classes, functions etc. You never know if eventually someone who doesn't speak your language has to read your code (e.g. when you post it on SO). Second of all, I'm unsure as to what part in your code you're refering to; there are two different methods in which HTML is being parsed.
Anyway, I assume you're refering to `doInBackground()` from class `Logo`. You basically already achieved exactly what you're looking for in the `ParsingPaginaWeb` class. You loop over each found `<img>` and fetch the respective image:

```
for(Element img : document.select("div.news-col-0 img[src]")) {
    String src = img.attr("src");
    InputStream is = new java.net.URL(src).openStream();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    /* save the bitmap or pass it somewhere else,
       otherwise, it will simply be overwritten */
}
```

You are probably going to have to change the data types in which you store the bitmaps, since you're retrieving more than one. You could use a `List<Bitmap>` to store them for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answere and thanks for your suggest. Anyway.. Now i edited the question and i put the Adapter code. Using your code i have same problem and i display only the first image.. Maybe the problem is in the Adapter? Can you take a look at it? Thanks.

Comment: @End.Game You'll have to process each url **inside the loop**. The way you've implemented it, `ImgSrc` will be overwritten over and over again, and only the last image will be processed. Have a look at my edit.

Comment: But as you can see i have two different loops. One for titles and one for the bitmap and then in the `onPostExecute` i execute the Logo class `new Logo().execute();`. I don't know if could be the problem..

Comment: I suggest you only post the relevant parts of your code, since there certainly are irrelevant parts. That would make it easier for everyone to read your code and understand your train of thought.

Comment: the problem is that i can't find the parts that could be the real problem..have you got google plus?maybe you can help me through hangout..if you want

Comment: @End.Game Sorry, can't do that. I'm also not exactly an expert for android programming. However, I think your general problem is cardinalities or choosing data types respectively. If you want to display more than one image, you need to use a container that can do so. The fact that almost everything in your code is in Italian doesn't quite help understanding what's going on in your code...